# Sharepoint 2010 - Removing workflow association

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a site with a list **List1** and a workflow non reusable **Workflow1** associated to this list, and defined to be started with creation of new entries. As I need to do some big changes in the workflow, I decided to create a new list **List2** saving **List1** as a template, and then I created a Workflow2 similar to Workflow1, associated to **List2**, so I can use **List2** and **Workflow2** as development/test.

Everything seems to be Ok, only that somehow the production Workflow1 is now  associated to **List2** additional to **List1**, so every time a new entry is created in **List2**, the **Workflow1** is started.. When I go to **List2** in `Sharepoint Designer`, under Workflows I see **Workflow1** included, although **Workflow1** was created only for **List1**. It looks like when saving the list as a template, the association with existing workflows is maintained, so a new list created with the template will have that association.

Is there any way using `Sharepoint Designer` to remove this association between **List2** and **Workflow1**, without removing **Workflow1**? Or is there a way to avoid this **Workflow1** to start with new items in **List2**, but continue starting with **List1**?

I was looking for possible answers to this, but all I found were references to remove the workflow, which is not possible here as the workflow is in Production. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using designer, select the library, click on Workflow Associations, and that will take you to the library workflow association settings page in sharepoint. There click on Remove, block or restore a workflow, and there you have. Anyway, is there a reason why you want to use Designer instead of using the almight PowerShell?

```
$site= Get-SPSite SITEURL
if($site-ne $null)
{

    $Web = $site.rootWeb;
    # Get the list  to which we wanted to associate the workflow
    $SPList  = $Web.Lists[LISTNAME]; 

    $workflowAssociation  = $SPList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(YOUR ASSOCIATION NAME, [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

    if($workflowAssociation  -ne $null)
    {
        #  Remove workflow association from list
        $SPList.RemoveWorkflowAssociation($workflowAssociation);
        $SPList.Update();
        Write-Host  “Workflow association removed Successfully.” -foregroundcolor  “Green”
     }
     else
     {
         Write-Host  “Workflow association could not be found.” -foregroundcolor  “Yellow”
     }
     $Web.Dispose()
}
$s.Dispose()
```